# browserstack ctrl+enter keyboard event not registering in chrome or IE

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, keyboard-events, browserstack

I'm testing a feature on Browserstack and am unsure if it's really broken on Windows or if Browserstack is just not getting my keyboard events properly.

I'm trying to detect when the user presses ctrl+enter. I have a code snippet below that works fine in Chrome on my MacBook. However, when I use Browserstack to run it in Windows 10 with Chrome 87 (Latest), it does not register the correct keyboard event.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. On a MacBook, go to [www.browserstack.com](https://www.browserstack.com)
2. Start a live session with this post as the url: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65113392`
3. Choose Windows 10 Chrome 87 (Latest)
4. Click the Run the code snippet button below inside Browserstack
5. Click on the input field
6. Press ctrl+enter

**Expected behavior:** I see "key: Enter, ctrlKey: true"

**Observed behavior:** I see "key: Control, ctrlKey: true"

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input')
const output = document.getElementById('output')
input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  output.innerText = `key: ${e.key}, ctrlKey: ${e.ctrlKey}`
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it. Here in Chrome and Edge (IE refused to load and opened Edge), it changes from "Control, ctrlKey: true" to "Enter, ctrlKey: true" as soon as I press Enter. Of course, it makes the additional step with the control key because the control key was the first key to go down ("keydown").

Comment: @E.Zacarias what version of windows and chrome are you using?

Comment: @E.Zacarias I just reproduced it again on Windows 10 with Chrome 87 (latest). What kind of keyboard are you using? I'm on a MacBook keyboard.

Comment: You are right, I'm on a PC keyboard (Windows 10, Chrome 87.0.4280.88). Did you try other combinations, like Command+Enter? I can't help more than that, but I know that Ctrl key of PC is not the same as in Mac. Reference: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/switching-to-the/9781449372927/ch01s08.html

Comment: @E.Zacarias Yes, I tried Cmd+Enter. Interestingly, Cmd registers as Ctrl as well but has the same problem as Ctrl+Enter. I submitted a help ticket to Browserstack and they confirmed they were able to reproduce the bug but have not yet found a root cause.

Comment: I just got another update from Browserstack. It says, "I would want to share that our engineering team investigated the issue. However, the root cause still remains unidentified. Having said that, the team would be re-visiting this case in sub-sequent iterations and I will be sure to keep you notified with the updates as well as update the stack overflow question. For now, I am temporarily archiving this ticket from our end. However, I will re-open the ticket once we identify the root cause and update you." Sounds like they couldn't figure it out and gave up. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke to Browerstack's customer service. They were able to confirm it's a bug in Browserstack. I think it has to do with the way they switch cmd and ctrl keys. In any case, it sounds like they aren't prioritizing the bug.

If you're working on an app where you need to press ctrl+enter (e.g. to submit a comment so users can use the enter key for creating newlines), your best bet for testing is https://www.lambdatest.com. I checked all the other major competitors and LambdaTest is the only one that has free live testing, although you do need to register for an account unlike with Browserstack. LambdaTest doesn't have this bug so I was able to test the feature there just fine.